# Problem installing importlib on Mac with pip3

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, python-3.7

Good morning!

Until yesterday I was using python 2.7 and using the following code for writing output files for my scripts:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

But now I'm upgrading my code to python 3.7, so now I need to use `importlib.reload`instead of just `reload`. However, typing `sudo -H pip3 install importlib` on my shell gives me the following error:

```
Collecting importlib
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/77/3781f65cafe55480b56914def99022a5d2965a4bb269655c89ef2f1de3cd/importlib-1.0.4.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import distutils.core
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
    import importlib.util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-3cz_3d6n/importlib/
```

After looking for solutions I also tried to upgrade setuptools, but that didn't fix my problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[`importlib` at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/importlib/) is an outdated package intended for [very old Python versions](https://github.com/brettcannon/importlib#notice-about-maintenance). For new versions of Python `importlib` is [a module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), you don't need to install it, it's always available.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, however, it fails anyway because reload doesn't exist apparently :(